# jquery with two or more sub selectors

Tags: jquery

How do I write a selector that has two condtional selectors, eg

```
$("#version option:selected **AND** option:contains('some text')")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like you can use `:visited:hover` in CSS, you could do the same in jQuery:

```
$("#version option:selected:contains('some text')")
```

Comment: Thanks. That was the first thing I tried. Must have had a typo somewhere. It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

BTW, the correct usage would be in your case:

```
$("#version option:selected, #version option:contains('some text')")
```

**or**

```
$("#version").find("option:selected, option:contains('some text')")
```

**not**

```
$("#version option:selected, option:contains('some text')")
```

Comment: Whoa... both answered at "0 secs ago."  That's a first for me :D

Comment: Not sure if this is what the OP asks. I interpret the question as: how can I select elements that are both selected and contain a certain piece of text

Comment: That does not work.
$("#version option:selected, #version option:contains('some text')") is a logical OR, I need a logical AND

Answer (score 1):

You can match on multiple attribute selectors by simply chaining further sub 'find' calls.

For example:

```
$("#version option:selected").find(":contains('some text')") //and so forth
```

Answer (score 0):

You separate the selectors by commas:

```
$("#version option:selected,#version option:contains('some text')")
```

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

**Update**

Even though this is not what the OP was looking for I updated my post in case someone stumbles upon this in the future. Thanks to ***RoToRa*** for catching the error.